# Android Packages in SDK Manager

Tags: android, package

I just started programming Android applications. I have installed everything, but I wonder: Do I have to install all the packages specified by Android SDK Manager? If not, how do I know the most important ones for someone just starting out?

Answer (score 1):

You only install the packages that you want.  You need to determine what version of Android you are going to write apps for, but if you are in doubt download all of them.  Remember that you can write an app in a later version of Android, but make it compatible with earlier versions when you create your project.  Another option is to look and see what version of Android is most popular, 2.3, and use it.  That is just a few ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily have to have everything installed, though, it doesn't hurt to.  You only need to download the version of the SDK with which you would like to program against.  So, if you want to write your application to work on ICS, you would download only the APIs corresponding to that version, which I believe is 14, though I'm not in front of my workstation to verify.

If you want to program on earlier versions such as Gingerbread, then you would download the 2.3 version of the APIs and so on and so on.

Additionally, you will need to get APIs to certain devices from Samsung, Kyocera and the likes if you're going to support specific hardware functions to those said devices.